# How much heat energy MAX would be produced from one kWh of energy?

Tags: heat, electricity

I'm researching about possible green energy sources and for one of my problems I needed to know exactly how much heat one kWh produces. Use as much resistance as you need to produce as much heat as is possible

Comment: What color is my blue tie?  How is this not just a *really basic* unit conversion question?

Comment: Resistance heating is *always* 100% efficient at turning a higher 'class' of energy (electrical) into a lower 'class' (heat). But you can achieve greater than 100% efficiency if you use a heat-pump.

Comment: Turn on a small room heater for an hour and find out? Or try four of them for 15 minutes if you are in a hurry. It is similar to how much heat a car absorbs on a sunny, windless day.

Comment: @brhans And a 1 kW motor feeding coal in to a furnace could produce a lot more. Motor feeding uranium in to a reactor... Motor feeding antimatter into the Sun...

Answer (score 7):

> how much heat one kWh produces

1 kWh, which can also be expressed as 3.6 MJ, 3412 BTU, and various other measures of energy.

Comment: I love this answer.

Comment: About the energy of a cup of gasoline.